# Condição para query sql oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Eu tenho um serviço de busca de informações de usuários por sua matrícula em uma tabela x. A matrícula que eu recebo como parâmetro para a busca vem completa (Ex: T111111), enquanto no banco ela está cadastrada de outra forma (Ex: 001111), onde pode aparecer apenas os últimos 4,5,6 dígitos da matrícula. Por conta disso, estou tentando construir uma query onde aborde todas essa condições. Até aí tudo bem, pois posso usar substring, mas se o usuário for estagiário ele vem com a matrícula completa (E11111), e nesse caso o meu substring muda.

Exemplificando:

- Matricula Estagiário = E11111 -> Substr(matriculaFunc, 2)
- Matricula Não Estagiário = U111111 ->    Substr(matriculaFunc, 4)

Portanto, estou tentando construir uma query onde verifica se o usuário é estágiário e utiliza o substring correto para sua condição, e se ele não for também.

O que cheguei até agora foi isso, mas não está funcionando corretamente:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT( CASE 
                           WHEN #MATRICULA_FUNC LIKE 'E%' THEN SUBSTR(#MATRICULA_FUNC, 2) 
                           ELSE SUBSTR(#MATRICULA_FUNC, 4) 
                         END ) AS SUBSTR_MAT 
        FROM X) SUBMAT, X
WHERE  MATRICULA LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBMAT.SUBSTR_MAT);
```

A ideia que tive foi criar uma nova tabela com a substring para poder comparar a substr_mat com a matrícula cadastrada na tabela x. Enfim, não está funcionando corretamente e queria saber como posso fazer pra trazer todas essas informações do usuário nessa tabela, mediante a sua substring de matrícula está corretamente feita.

Comment: De acordo com sua explicação não bastaria a utilização do operador `OR` com as diversas condições possíveis na cláusula `WHERE`?

Comment: Olá @João facilitaria se você incluísse na pergunta um script para criação das tabelas e outro para inserção de alguns dados de exemplo.